# How to Print Summary of Packages that Can be Updated?

Tags: package-management

When I log into Ubuntu Server 12.04 LTS, I'm met with a message that looks something like this:

```
6 packages can be updated.
6 updates are security updates.
```

How can I get a detailed summary of the updates above?

I don't want to *blindly* install these updates with `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`.

I'd like to know what I'm installing before I install it, or even pick and choose which updates I want to apply.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are using `apt-get`/`aptitude` you can use `-V` to show a detailed status of the packages to be upgraded, if you add more `V`'s the report will be more verbose:

```
sudo apt-get -VV upgrade 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following package was automatically installed and is no longer required:
   linux-image-3.13-1-amd64 (3.13.10-1)
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove it.
The following packages have been kept back:
   chromium-inspector (33.0.1750.152-1 => 34.0.1847.116-1~deb7u1)
The following packages will be upgraded:
   aspell-es (1.11-7 => 1.11-8)
   dbus (1.8.0-3 => 1.8.2-1)
   dbus-x11 (1.8.0-3 => 1.8.2-1)
   debugedit (4.11.2-2.1 => 4.11.2-3)
   file (5.17-1 => 5.18-1)
   file-roller (3.12.0-1 => 3.12.1-2)
   fonts-opensymbol (102.3+LibO4.1.5-2 => 102.3+LibO4.1.6~rc2-1)
   ispanish (1.11-7 => 1.11-8)
   libdbus-1-3:amd64 (1.8.0-3 => 1.8.2-1)
   libdbus-1-3 (1.8.0-3 => 1.8.2-1)
   libdbus-1-dev (1.8.0-3 => 1.8.2-1)
   libidn11 (1.28-1 => 1.28-2)
   libidn11-dev (1.28-1 => 1.28-2)
   libmagic1 (5.17-1 => 5.18-1)
   libmailutils4 (2.99.98-1.1 => 2.99.98-1.2)
   libneon27-gnutls (0.30.0-1 => 0.30.0-2)
   libreoffice-base-core (4.1.5-2+b1 => 4.1.6~rc2-1+b1)
   libreoffice-calc (4.1.5-2+b1 => 4.1.6~rc2-1+b1)
   libreoffice-common (4.1.5-2 => 4.1.6~rc2-1)
   libreoffice-core (4.1.5-2+b1 => 4.1.6~rc2-1+b1)
   libreoffice-java-common (4.1.5-2 => 4.1.6~rc2-1)
   libreoffice-math (4.1.5-2+b1 => 4.1.6~rc2-1+b1)
   libreoffice-script-provider-python (4.1.5-2 => 4.1.6~rc2-1)
   libreoffice-style-galaxy (4.1.5-2 => 4.1.6~rc2-1)
   libreoffice-writer (4.1.5-2+b1 => 4.1.6~rc2-1+b1)
   librpm3 (4.11.2-2.1 => 4.11.2-3)
   librpmbuild3 (4.11.2-2.1 => 4.11.2-3)
   librpmio3 (4.11.2-2.1 => 4.11.2-3)
   librpmsign1 (4.11.2-2.1 => 4.11.2-3)
   mailutils (2.99.98-1.1 => 2.99.98-1.2)
   mailutils-common (2.99.98-1.1 => 2.99.98-1.2)
   myspell-es (1.11-7 => 1.11-8)
   php5-json (1.3.4-3 => 1.3.5-1)
   python-magic (5.17-1 => 5.18-1)
   python3-magic (5.17-1 => 5.18-1)
   python3-uno (4.1.5-2+b1 => 4.1.6~rc2-1+b1)
   rpm (4.11.2-2.1 => 4.11.2-3)
   rpm-common (4.11.2-2.1 => 4.11.2-3)
   rpm2cpio (4.11.2-2.1 => 4.11.2-3)
   rubygems-integration (1.6 => 1.7)
   sysstat (10.2.1-1 => 10.3.1-1)
   systemd-ui (3-1 => 3-2)
   uno-libs3 (4.1.5-2+b1 => 4.1.6~rc2-1+b1)
   ure (4.1.5-2+b1 => 4.1.6~rc2-1+b1)
44 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1 not upgraded.
Need to get 12.8 MB/91.4 MB of archives.
After this operation, 186 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] n
```